# Better way of initializing a deck of cards

Tags: ruby, loops, playing-cards

Is there an easier way of doing this instead of inserting each element into the array manually

```
stack_of_cards << Card.new("A", "Spades", 1)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("2", "Spades", 2)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("3", "Spades", 3)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("4", "Spades", 4)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("5", "Spades", 5)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("6", "Spades", 6)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("7", "Spades", 7)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("8", "Spades", 8)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("9", "Spades", 9)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("10", "Spades", 10)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("J", "Spades", 11)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("Q", "Spades", 12)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("K", "Spades", 13)

stack_of_cards << Card.new("A", "Hearts", 1)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("2", "Hearts", 2)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("3", "Hearts", 3)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("4", "Hearts", 4)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("5", "Hearts", 5)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("6", "Hearts", 6)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("7", "Hearts", 7)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("8", "Hearts", 8)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("9", "Hearts", 9)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("10", "Hearts", 10)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("J", "Hearts", 11)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("Q", "Hearts", 12)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("K", "Hearts", 13)

stack_of_cards << Card.new("A", "Diamonds", 1)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("2", "Diamonds", 2)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("3", "Diamonds", 3)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("4", "Diamonds", 4)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("5", "Diamonds", 5)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("6", "Diamonds", 6)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("7", "Diamonds", 7)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("8", "Diamonds", 8)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("9", "Diamonds", 9)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("10", "Diamonds", 10)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("J", "Diamonds", 11)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("Q", "Diamonds", 12)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("K", "Diamonds", 13)

stack_of_cards << Card.new("A", "Clubs", 1)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("2", "Clubs", 2)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("3", "Clubs", 3)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("4", "Clubs", 4)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("5", "Clubs", 5)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("6", "Clubs", 6)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("7", "Clubs", 7)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("8", "Clubs", 8)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("9", "Clubs", 9)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("10", "Clubs", 10)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("J", "Clubs", 11)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("Q", "Clubs", 12)
stack_of_cards << Card.new("K", "Clubs", 13)
```

Comment: Devise a scheme to represent each card with a number, write methods to determine its face and type. Then just populate a array using a loop number from 1 to 52

Answer (score 6):

Just loop over both ranks and suits.

```
ranks = %w{A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K}
suits = %w{Spades Hearts Diamonds Clubs}
suits.each do |suit|
  ranks.size.times do |i|
    stack_of_cards << Card.new( ranks[i], suit, i+1 )
  end
end
```

Comment: I might alternatively suggest that the inner loop should be: `ranks.each_with_index do |rank,i|` allowing one to replace `ranks[i]` with `rank`.

Comment: I'd use `suits.product(ranks.with_index.to_a).map do |suit, (rank, index)|`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is: Create an array of faces and an array of suits then iterate over them in a nested loop. Also change the `Card` class so that you don't need to specify the face as a string an integer as that is redundant. It's most convenient if you only need to specify the int parameter.

This way the code would look like this:

```
faces = 1..13
suits = %w(Spades Hearts Diamonds Clubs)
cards = suits.flat_map do |suit|
  faces.map |face_int_value|
    Card.new(suit, face_int_value)
  end
end
```

Or in ruby before 1.9.2:

```
faces = 1..13
suits = %w(Spades Hearts Diamonds Clubs)
cards = suits.map do |suit|
  faces.map |face_int_value|
    Card.new(suit, face_int_value)
  end
end.flatten
```

Comment: +1. Despite my at least superficial familiarity with Scala's `for` comprehensions and C#'s LINQ query comprehensions, both of which are built on `flatMap` (or `SelectMany` as .NET calls it), I always forget that it is also in `Enumerable` now.

Answer (score 1):

First off: why do you represent the rank and the value of a card separately? Is there ever an instance where, say, a Jack does *not* have the value 11? For example, why do you have

```
Card.new("7", "Spades", 7)
```

instead of just

```
Card.new(7, "Spades")
```

and is there ever an instance where you would have

```
Card.new("7", "Spades", 42)
```

If not, then those two should be packaged together into an object.

Also, why are the suits represented as strings and not as `Suit`s or at least as symbols?

I'd probably do something like this:

```
Rank = Struct.new(:rank, :value) do
  def to_s; rank end
  alias_method :inspect, :to_s
end

Card = Struct.new(:rank, :suit) do
  def to_s; "#{rank} of #{suit.capitalize}" end
  alias_method :inspect, :to_s
end

ranks = %w[Ace 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Jack Queen King].map.with_index {|rank, value|
  Rank.new(rank, value + 1)
}

suits = [:spades, :hearts, :diamonds, :clubs]

deck = suits.product(ranks).map {|suit, rank| Card.new(rank, suit) }
```

Comment: Struct has its own problems, due to mutability. You don't want to allow `card.suit = -9`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Mark Rushakoff solution and using Ruby 1.9

```
Card = Struct.new(:rank, :suit,:rank_id) 
ranks = %w{A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K}
suits = %w{Spades Hearts Diamonds Clubs}
stack_of_cards = suits.each_with_object([]) do |suit,res|
  ranks.size.times do |i|
    res << Card.new(ranks[i], suit,i + 1)
  end
end
puts stack_of_cards.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

David A. Black's *[The Well Grounded Rubyist](http://www.manning.com/black2/)* uses deck initialization as a way to demonstrate the `cycle` method. I think the resulting code is clever, and very simple:

```
class Card 
  SUITS = %w{ clubs diamonds hearts spades } 
  RANKS=%w{2345678910JQKA}
  class Deck 
    attr_reader :cards
    def initialize(n=1) 
      @cards = [] SUITS.cycle(n) do |s|
        RANKS.cycle(1) do |r| @cards << "#{r} of #{s}"
        end
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

Also, the [Ruby Quiz #1: The Solitaire Cipher](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz1.html) involved using a deck of cards to encode a message. Check out the solutions. You'll see a few different ways used to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Card = Struct.new(:name, :suit,:number) 
stack_of_cards = []
%w{'Spades Hearts Diamonds Clubs'}.each do |suit|
    %w{'A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K'}.each_with_index do |name, i|
        stack_of_cards << Card.new(name, suit, i+1) 
    end
end
p stack_of_cards
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to make a card deck in Ruby.

### 1. An array of arrays

...easier, but may be tougher if you need to compare cards against each other (courtesy code project from Tealeaf Academy)

```
values = ["A", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "J", "Q", "K" ]
suits = [ "hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds" ]
deck = values.product(suits)

=> [["A", "hearts"], ["A", "spades"], ["A", "clubs"], ["A", "diamonds"] #etc...
```

You can also add on .shuffle or .shuffle! to the deck

```
deck = values.product(suits).shuffle

=> [[9, "diamonds"], [2, "clubs"], [7, "spades"], [4, "clubs"] #etc...
```

### 2. An array of hashes with numerical scores associated with each card

...so you can easily sort or compare cards via "scores" (courtesy @amaseda at General Assembly DC)

```
def deck_o_cards
  values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
  suits = ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'clubs', 'spades']
  deck = []

  values.each_with_index do |v, i|
    suits.each do |s|
      deck.push({
        score: i,
        value: v,
        suit: s,
      })
    end
  end

  return deck.shuffle
end

=> [{:score=>8, :value=>10, :suit=>"hearts"}, {:score=>4, :value=>6, :suit=>"diamonds"}, #etc...
```